# How to run sbt multiple command in interactive mode as one command?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to refine sbt assembly/package operation by combine two step to one.
The two step is:

```
$ sbt
> project XXX
....
> assembly
Ctrl + c to exit
```

Besides, `assembly` is a task form fat jar sbt plugin.
I have attempt with `sbt project analysis assembly` but not works.A error encounter:

```
[error] Not a valid command: analysis (similar: alias)
[error] Not a valid key: analysis (similar: readAnalysis, mainClass, less)
[error] analysis
[error]         ^
```

How to achieve this?Thanks

Comment: `analysis` is not an sbt command (unless you defined it or imported). You want it to be the parameter of `project` command, right? Sbt can't read your mind so you need to help it: `sbt "project analysis" assembly`. Hope it works, also see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Running-Commands.html#Pass+arguments+to+a+command+or+task+in+batch+mode

Comment: Thanks, `sbt "project analysis" assembly` works.The `analysis` keywords is my project name I just don't know how to switch project with one line cmd. Could you put a answer?

Comment: The duplicated question doesn't answer the actual question in the title: running multiple commands in interactive mode. The answer of [@Justin Kaeser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43342323/1206998) below answers it.

Comment: I followed SO recommandation and made [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44457452/1206998)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Within the sbt shell, use `;` to chain commands:

```
;project XXX; assembly
```

Calling from the command line, enclose individual commands with quotes:

```
sbt "project XXX" assembly
```

or enclose a whole chain in quotes:

```
sbt ";project XXX; assembly"
```

To call a task in subproject `XXX` from the context of another project in the shell:

```
XXX/assembly
```

Comment: I've ask the more precis question about running several command within the sbt shell. I copied your answer, but it would be fair that you get the credit. If you add your above answer, or simply copy my adapted version, I'll remove mine