# How to run sbt multiple command in interactive mode

Tags: sbt

I want to run several sbt-commands within sbt interactive mode, i.e. without leaving the sbt "shell"?

(Note: 
[Some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20589951/1206998) answer how to pass argument to sbt-commands using sbt in the standard shell. Not what I wnat here)

Example: I am in sbt interactive shell, and I want to run "test:compile", then "test"

I know test will call required compilation, but in this example I want to run the compilation of all sub-projects, before any test is started.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To run commands sequentially within the sbt shell, use `;` to chain commands:

```
> ;test:compile ;test
```

Note however that running the `test` task will compile your sources if necessary without you having to explicitly running the `compile` task.